# Setting CPU affinity using taskset

Tags: affinity

I am using the taskset tool to set CPU affinity for one of my programs. How do I set the affinity on a single CPU only - since I was not sure about this, so I was doing this:

```
taskset -c 2-2 tests/prog 1 2 3
```

...expecting, that I am scheduling the program to run on CPU #2 only, following the similar way for other CPUs. Even if I'm right, this is a bad way to perform what I want IMO, can I get some help?

Thank you,
Sayan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`taskset -c 2 ...` should work to pin the program to CPU #2 (which is the third CPU -- CPUs are numbered from 0).

> Even if I'm right, this is a bad way to perform what I want IMO, can I get some help?

Depends on what you want. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was under the impression that taskset -c 2 would schedule the program on CPU#0, CPU#1 and CPU#2. Thank you for clarifying. I just want to run a program from a specific CPU at a time. BTW, was my syntax on the original question correct?

Comment: Correct. `taskset -c 2-2` also works, it's just unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be using the CPU masks like

```
taskset -p mask pid

#taskset -p  0x00000001 11587
pid 11587's current affinity mask: ff
pid 11587's new affinity mask: 1
```